# add basic auth with traefik v2 in kubernetes did not popup login form

Tags: kubernetes

I am follow this steps to add basic auth to treafik 2.1.6,first create kuberntes(v1.15.2) secret:

```
openssl rand -base64 32
htpasswd -bc auth dabai-admin hbzwvEbfRGSN4MAiycCVM30stfGjzR6dZPDh9bS5te4=
kubectl create secret generic treafik-secret-name --from-file=auth -n kube-system
```

create middleware:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: basic-auth
spec:
  basicAuth:
    secret: treafik-secret-name
```

tweak traefik config and add middleware we create:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: traefik-dashboard-route
annotations:
  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
  ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
  ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: traefik-secret-name
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: Host(`traefik.example.com`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: traefik
          port: 8080
      middlewares:
        - name: basic-auth
```

finally when I access the domain `traefik.example.com`,it did not pop up login form, what should I do to make it work? I want to add basic auth to my website `traefik.example.com`.

Comment: You need to provide more details, also how exactly did you tested it?

Comment: visit url `http://traefik.example.com`  from chrome web browser to test the authorizon.@Crou

Comment: I guess you are mixing crd configuration with ingress configuration. Can you show your traefik configuration especially the part with a provider?